# Console Log Result of ApiKey Demo

Tags: javascript, api

Hello i'm writing following code in order to displaying consol.log value 10 EUR to AUD
I read documentation here https://apilayer.com/marketplace/fixer-api#documentation-tab
under GET/ convert tab
What i'm doing wrong?

```js
    function myFunction() {
        var myHeaders = new Headers();
        myHeaders.append("apikey", "myApi");
        var requestOptions = {
            method: 'GET',
            redirect: 'follow',
            headers: myHeaders
        };

        fetch("https://api.apilayer.com/currency_data/convert?to=AUD&from=EUR&amount=10", requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(result => console.log(result))
            .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Currency Converter</h1>
        <form id="form" onsubmit="myFunction()">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="From">From Currency</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="from" required type="text" value="EUR" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="To">To Currency</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="to" required type="text" value="AUD" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="amount" required type="number" value="10" />
            </div>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
```

Documetation API code

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("apikey", "set7MJ58G82xHoRWGW69o7pqn6DqVJQL");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  redirect: 'follow',
  headers: myHeaders
};

fetch("https://api.apilayer.com/fixer/convert?to={to}&from={from}&amount={amount}", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Comment: What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: The problem that you are having is you are running the function on form submit. But the form then gets submitted to the current URL before the API results can be returned. There are many solutions for this. A quick and basic solution is change your onsubmit to include a return false so the form doesn't get submitted. **onsubmit="myFunction();return false;"** But there are many many solutions to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `onsubmit` function in the form tag to prevent form submit event as

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); myFunction();">
```